# What is the right projection to use?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am working on an application which uses lat and lon coordinates. The coordinates I'm working with can be found all over the globe.

For some reason I have to do some operations in meters, buffering for example.

I know that working in EPSG:3857 can sometimes lead to inaccuracies which can become significant at the pole level when working with distances and in particular buffers.

I'm kind of new with GIS, but I might understand that depending on the place and the issue, the best projection to use could be different.

My questions are:

- How to know what kind of projection to use ?
- Is there like a rule, for example if latitude > 60, and I need to use meters, use this projection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest considering UTM, a projected coordinate system (metric). This system is projected using WGS84 ellipsoid and it is worldwide coordinate, which means each country has a different zone. Just ask google for UTM, and it will show you the whole globe split into zones. The beauty is that, due to its project using WGS84, it is extremely easy to convert into WGS84 (geographic coordinates) or Web Mercator (3857). Keep in mind, that if you use local coordinates for different countries and you may need to merge data, will be a pain to transform the datasets. Especially if you are planning to publish into a web app (you may need WGS84 or Web Mercator for it).

Answer (score 0):

First option: see if there is an established standard for your region of interest. Some countries use a kind of national grid, like [Ordnance Survey National Grid/British National Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid) for Great Britain or [Swiss National Grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_coordinate_system) for Switzerland or [Ghana National Grid](https://epsg.io/2136) for Ghana.

Sometimes, especially for larger countries, such standards might exist on sub-national level for administrative units.

See [Spatial Reference Website](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2056/) where you find a list of different CRS definitions/EPSG codes with a short description that should help you decide if a CRS for a certain area can be used for measurements:

[image]

Alternatively, use the local [UTM zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). UTM is a system that is available worldwide and divided earth in 60 zones: strips of 6° of longitude in width. To find out in what zone your region of interest is you an use the website [What UTM Zone am I in ?](https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-#)

Comment: So the solution is to have a file, teeling for each country what projection to use, then when i have an aoi, i check in what coutry it belongs ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your workflow, what you want to do. Your question was about how to find a projection. It does not depend on "file", but on the extent of the geometries you want to use. In the same file, you could have geometries that need different treatment. Without more information it's impossible to say what you should do. Please post this as another question and add more details.

Comment: Information about the EPSGs can also be found on this source: https://epsg.org/home.html